# linker command failed: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, vscode

Me manda un error error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) en un programa c++, en visual studio code con Xcode

error completo

```cpp
cd "/Users/luismartinez/Desktop/escritorio/Prueba/Actividad-5/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/luismartinez/Desktop/escritorio/Prueba/Actividad-5/"main
luismartinez@MacBook-Pro-de-Luis-2 Prueba % cd "/Users/luismartinez/Desktop/escritorio/Prueba/Actividad-5/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/luismartinez/Desktop/escritorio/Prueba/Activida
d-5/"main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Alumno::setCarrera(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
  "Alumno::cumpleaños()", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
  "Alumno::setMatricula(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
  "Alumno::imprimeAlumno()", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
  "Alumno::setEdad(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
  "Alumno::setNombre(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
  "Alumno::Alumno(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
  "Alumno::Alumno()", referenced from:
      _main in main-9a51fb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
luismartinez@MacBook-Pro-de-Luis-2 Actividad-5 %
```

Archivo Main

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Alumno.h"

using std::cout; 

int main() {
  Alumno p1("A01748087", "Diego", 19, "IRS"); // puedes usar llaves o ()
  Alumno p2;  

  p2.setMatricula("A01748090");
  p2.setNombre("María");
  p2.setEdad(20);
  p2.setCarrera("Relaciones");
   
  p1.imprimeAlumno();
  p2.imprimeAlumno();  
  p1.cumpleaños();
  p1.imprimeAlumno();
}
```

Archivo Alumno

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Alumno.h"
using std::string;
using std::cout;

Alumno::Alumno(string matricula, string nombre, int edad, string carrera) {

    this->matricula = matricula;
    this->nombre = nombre;
    this->edad = edad;
    this-> carrera = carrera;
    }

Alumno::Alumno(){
  matricula="";
  nombre="";
  edad=0;
  carrera="";
}

void Alumno::setMatricula(string matricula){
  this-> matricula = matricula;
}
void Alumno::setNombre(string nombre){
  this->nombre = nombre;
}
void Alumno::setEdad(int edad){
  this->edad= edad;
}
void Alumno::setCarrera(string carrera){
  this->carrera= carrera;
}
void Alumno::imprimeAlumno(){
  cout << "(" << getMatricula() << ", " << getNombre() << ", " << getEdad() << ", " << getCarrera() << ")\n";  
}

int Alumno::cumpleaños(){
  return(this -> edad = edad + 1);
}
```

Archivo Alumno.h

```cpp
#include <string>
#ifndef ALUMNO_H
#define ALUMNO_H
using std::string;

class Alumno{
private:
  string matricula;
  string nombre;
  int edad;
  string carrera;

public:

Alumno(string matricula, string nombre, int edad, string carrera);

Alumno();

string getMatricula(){return matricula;}
string getNombre(){return nombre;}
int getEdad(){return edad;}
string getCarrera(){return carrera;}

void setMatricula(string matricula);
void setNombre(string nombre);
void setEdad(int edad);
void setCarrera(string carrera);
void imprimeAlumno();
int cumpleaños();
};


#endif
```

Comment: Comparte el error completo. Que el linker retorne 1 solo significa que hubo un error, no nos dice que error hubo. Probablemente no estes compilando bien o se te haya olvidado definir una funcion. Puedes compartir el error completo y la forma en la que estas compilando?

Comment: El código siempre es mejor compartirlo como texto que como imagen.

Comment: Listo !!! es el error completo y estoy compilando con Xcode 13,3 para Mac desde Visual Studio Code

Comment: Agregué los tres archivos y únicamente instalé en la compu Mac en terminal Xcode para compilar

Comment: Por favor, pásate por [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber como funciona el sitio. Puedes empezar por lo que es un [mcve], y también [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente el problema no sucede al compilar.

Lo que tienes es un problema al linkear las unidades de traducción, porque no encuentra las definiciones que necesita.

Cuando tienes el código repartido en varios archivos .cpp, debes incluir cada uno en la línea de comandos, así se compilarán todos y se unirán correctamente.

En tu caso, tu línea de comandos debería ser así:

```
g++ main.cpp alumno.cpp -o main
```